# How to clear cookies programmatically on Blackberry 10?

Tags: cookies, cordova, blackberry-10

We need to clear cookies programmatically on Blackberry 10. Our app is written using cordova (phonegap) 2.8.0. One approach that we have considered is writing a custom plugin, which would call WebStorage.clearCookies() method. But, I believe we can't call casacade API (like this one) into the custom plugin code (c++ based).

Any alternative approach or corrections?

Thanks in advance